# Replicating "Join Attributes by Location" using pyQgis

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, attribute-joins, spatial-join, qgis-processing

I would like to replicate the behaviour of the "Join Attributes by Location" function of the Qgis GUI (Vector >> Data Management Tools >> Join Attributes by Location) using a pyQgis script. I attempt this with the following call:

```
processing.runalg("qgis:joinattributesbylocation",
                  "path/to/points.shp", 
                  "path/to/polygons.shp",
                  u'intersects',
                  0,
                  0,
                  '',
                  1,
                  "path/to/output.shp")
```

This works except that the resulting `output.shp` does not contain all the fields of `points.shp`, it contains only the first two, which happen to be longitude and latitude.

When I use the GUI operation, the resulting `output.shp` retains all the fields of `points.shp` and `polygons.shp`. How do I ensure that all fields of the target vector appear in the output vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`processing.runalg()` can be called with only two arguments: a string indicating which algorithm to be used, e.g. `"qgis:joinattributesbylocation"`, and a python dictionary object indicating parameter values which should not default, e.g. `{PARAMETER_KEY:parameter_value}`. Parameters left out of the dictionary fall back on their default values. Use the parameter names as presented in `processing.alghelp()` as keys.

To use the default behaviour, as the GUI Qgis call does, simply use default values. The complete call *could* be

```
processing.runalg("qgis:joinattributesbylocation",{
                        "TARGET":"path/to/points.shp", 
                        "JOIN":"path/to/polygons.shp", 
                        "OUTPUT":"path/to/output.shp"})
```

However, most processing algorithms have parameters that must be given. In that case, Qgis will present a warning such as:

```
Error: Missing parameter value for parameter PARAMETER_KEY
```

Using trial and error, can figure out which parameters are included in the minimum requirement. In this case, the complete call is:

```
processing.runalg("qgis:joinattributesbylocation",{
                        "TARGET":"path/to/points.shp", 
                        "JOIN":"path/to/polygons.shp",
                        "PREDICATE":u'intersects',
                        "SUMMARY":0,
                        "KEEP":1,
                        "OUTPUT":"path/to/output.shp"})
```