# Joining attributes by location for multiple layers using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes

Using the script below, I've created a list of catchment area corresponding to a list of outlets. It works perfectly but I would like to keep the attributes of my outlets in my catchment area layers (output_3 in my script).

In order to do so I've added a new output (output4) to join each outlet layer to its corresponding catchment area.

```
import processing
import os # This is is needed in the pyqgis console also
from qgis.core import (QgsVectorLayer)
#provide path to outflow points where x, y are stored in fields named 'x', 'y' (or rename geom.asPoint() to match your coordinates fields)
path_outlet = 'F:/outlet.shp'

#provide path to filled and clipped DEM
path_filled_DEM = 'F:/mnt_surcreuse.sdat'

#provide path where to store temporary outputs from processing algorythims 
path_to_temp_output1 = 'F:/upslope_raster{}.sdat'
path_to_temp_output2 = 'F:/polygonize{}.shp'
path_to_temp_output3 = 'F:/extract{}.shp'
path_to_temp_output4 = 'F:/final_output{}.shp'

#adds outflow point vector file to processing
outflow_points = QgsVectorLayer(path_outlet, "Outflow points layer", "ogr")


#iterates over all points in the outflow file. i is going to serve as polygone identifier
for i,f in enumerate(outflow_points.getFeatures()):

    #specifies geometry
    geom = f.geometry()

    #creates a raster file with upslope area
    output_1 = processing.run("saga:upslopearea", {'TARGET_PT_X': geom.asPoint().x(), 'TARGET_PT_Y': geom.asPoint().y(), 'ELEVATION': path_filled_DEM, 'METHOD': 0, 'AREA': path_to_temp_output1.format(str(i))})

    #converts raster to polygon
    output_2 = processing.run("gdal:polygonize", {'INPUT': output_1['AREA'], 'BAND': '1', 'OUTPUT': path_to_temp_output2.format(str(i))})

    #extracts only polygons with value 100
    output_3 = processing.run("qgis:extractbyattribute", {'INPUT': output_2['OUTPUT'], 'FIELD': 'DN', 'OPERATOR': '0', 'VALUE': '100', 'OUTPUT': path_to_temp_output3.format(str(i))})

    #add fields of each outlet layer to each corresponding upslope area
    output_4 = processing.run("qgis:joinattributesbylocation", {
        "TARGET": path_outlet,
        "JOIN": output_3,
        "PREDICATE": 'intersects',
        "SUMMARY": 0,
        "KEEP": 1,
        "OUTPUT": path_to_temp_output4.format(str(i))})
```

Unfortunately the script doesn't work and I get this error message instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptEditorDialog.py", line 224, in runAlgorithm
    exec(self.editor.text(), _locals)
  File "<string>", line 50, in <module>
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 106, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 137, in runAlgorithm
    raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: There were errors executing the algorithm.
Could not load source layer for INPUT: no value specified for parameter
```

(line 50 corresponds to the last line of the script)

Could someone help me solving this issue?

I am using QGIS 3.10.

Comment: Maybe you will find this thread helpfull [Replicating “Join Attributes by Location” using pyQgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209596/replicating-join-attributes-by-location-using-pyqgis).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could be wrong but you don't seem to set an INPUT in the `output4` declaration (hence the error message below your script returns).

> Could not load source layer for INPUT: no value specified for parameter

I would replace `JOIN` with `INPUT` like below

```
output_4 = processing.run("qgis:joinattributesbylocation", {
        "TARGET": path_exutoires,
        "INPUT": output_3["OUTPUT"], # I've changed the JOIN to INPUT
        "PREDICATE": 'intersects',
        "SUMMARY": 0,
        "KEEP": 1,
        "OUTPUT": path_to_temp_output4.format(str(i))})
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply ! Unfortunately I already tried to replace "JOIN" by "INPUT" but it didn't work (```Could not load source layer for INPUT: invalid value```)

Comment: Changed the code. How it behaves now?

Comment: I've created a small model using the fuction "join attributes by location" in order to have a closer look at its code. It turned out that it was "TARGET" that had to be replaced by "INPUT". I've edited my question with the new code but even after that change I still get the same error message (invalid value)... I really don't understand what's going on with my script... :(

Comment: When I want to be sure it works. First,  I open manually the processing toolbox. I run manually my algorithm with fixed layers. I look at Log tab as it displays the input parameters needed to run the algorithm. Then, I copy/paste the input dictionary block to my algorithm. I run it in Python. Then, I replace things with my variables if I need to loop and add logic.

Comment: @Thanks Thomas, I had complety forgotten that I had to add ```["OUTPUT"]``` next to ```output_3``` ! Thanks for your help ! It worked for a sample of 5 outlets and catchment areas so it should work for 300 now ! :)